# Change Runtime options Eclipse RCP dynamically

Tags: configuration, eclipse-rcp, e4

I bring a problem that is perhaps simple but I can't find how to fix it.

The application we are developing requires version 1.6 of the JRE, so we checked at the beginning that the version is correct. However, many users complained (clearly) as it needed more actual versions of java for other applications.

The solution (or workaround) was edit the eclipse.ini to add the -vm property and the path to the java version 1.6, that way they don't need to change the configuration of the system.

The problem is that they must edit the file by hand, so we wanted to see if it is possible, instead of displaying an error message and close the application, display a file dialog to select the path to the correct version of java (this part is easy) and once verified which is the correct version, add the entry "-vm " in eclipse.ini.

So, how we can do this? Or maybe there is a better way to do the same?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can put

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
```

in the `-vmargs` section of the eclipse.ini to specify that the Eclipse launcher should check for a minimum Java version of 1.6

Comment: Hello greg-449, the -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion checks for the minimum version, but I need to check for de maximum version (i.e. the application won't work well with another). Other possibility is to include the jre in the client, but I prefer resolve this in another way, if there is no other way maybe I'll do that